# Error by VCS tool on uvm_hdl_deposit usage on edaplayground

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm, edaplayground

I am trying to execute code @ https://www.edaplayground.com/x/e2Pe.
The code seems to be error free. However, when trying to simulate with VCS tool, it is giving me below error:

```
UVM_ERROR: set: unable to write to hdl path (top.dut_inst.BOOT_MODE)
You may not have sufficient PLI/ACC capabilites enabled for that path
              10    3.1 Force failed...
```

It looks like I need to set some options, but I am not aware. I tried giving `+vpi +acc`, but that did not work out.

Here is the complete command:

```
vcs -licqueue '+vpi' '+pli' '+acc' '-timescale=1ns/1ns' '+vcs+flush+all' '+warn=all' '-sverilog' +incdir+$UVM_HOME/src $UVM_HOME/src/uvm.sv $UVM_HOME/src/dpi/uvm_dpi.cc -CFLAGS -DVCS design.sv testbench.sv  && ./simv +vcs+lic+wait
```

Here is the relevant testbench code:

```
  if(uvm_hdl_deposit("top.dut_inst.BOOT_MODE",4'b0000)) begin
    $display($time,"\t1 Forced value...");
  end  else begin
    $display($time,"\t3.1 Force failed...");
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning message tells you what's wrong:

```
Warning-[DEPRECATED_OPTION] Deprecated option used
  The specified option '+acc' is deprecated.
  Please use '-debug_access+r+w+nomemcbk -debug_region+cell' instead.
```

When I replace `+acc` with `-debug_access+r+w+nomemcbk -debug_region+cell`, I no longer get `UVM_ERROR` messages, and I see this output:

```
              10    1 Forced value...
              20    1 Forced value...
              30    1 Forced value...
```

[Here is the modified edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ZehD)

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `-debug_all` flag in command will solve your problem.

In my case, only `-debug_all` works. But in your case, `-debug_access+all` works fine. Here is the [EDA link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/aCqp).